# Complex and interrelated data structure in the Client Server scenerio

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, data-structures

I need to know efficient mechanism used for data structure in the socket programming. Lets consider an example of car manufacturing on assembly line.

Initially Conveyer is empty then i start adding different parts dynamically. How can i transmit my data to the server using the TCP/UDP. What can i do so that my server can recognize, if i add some new part dynamically ? and after calculating server return data to client in same structure, so that client can put calculated data on the exact position of component.

Is it possible to arrange this data using some `B Tree` or `B+ Tree` structures ? is it possible to reconstruct the same tree on the server side ? what could be other possible  alternatives approaches to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your data, whatever you need to send to server, to some text or binary blob. Yeah, it's possible to serialize interrelated data structure, e.g. by assigning some ID to items and then referencing them by that ID. For C++ serialization I would recommend to have a look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

The simplest ID is memory address on serializer (sender) side - kind of unique identifier ready to use. Of course on deserializer side it must be considered as a just ID and not a memory address.

Comment: Thanks but do you know whats the difference it makes, if we use B tree as they provide some well defined way to insert and delete of the tree nodes. Why they could not be useful for my requirement ? could you please say some thing about this.

Comment: Sorry, the best way to describe a conveyor is a fixed size array until you provide more details about your design or requirements. And it's better to make this as a separate question.